# TOEFL: Cambridge tests vs Barron's tests (reading section)

Tags: reading

Yesterday I took TOEFL trial test in a testing centre and got 18/30 from reading section. It was a "Cambridge preparation for TOEFL test". Before that I had taken several "Barron's TOEFL iBT" tests at home and had always gotten minimum 25/30 from reading section. Now my question is whether the real TOEFL reading sections are close to Cambridge's tests or Barron's tests or maybe there is no rule?

Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about learning the language English.

Answer (score 3):

You can buy an [Official TOEFL iBT Tests](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071771263) and an [Official Guide to the TOEFL iBT](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071766588). I used these two reference books to prepare TOEFL tests.

Published two years ago, they are still good enough for you to prepare TOEFL tests, since the structure and contents of TOEFL iBT have not been changed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I will get back to it. However, my book is nearly 10 years old - is it still useful?